# Mercurial.Net Clone with http authorization

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket

I would like to clone a private repository with the help of mercurial.net.

I know I can clone a repo in the following way:

```
repository.Clone(repourl, new Mercurial.CloneCommand().WithObserver(new Mercurial.DebugObserver()).WithUpdate(false));
```

But it fails:

Additional information: abort: http authorization required for repourl

I searched a lot but I can't find a hg command to clone somehow like:

hg clone http://bitbucket.com/user/repo username/passowrd

Is there a way to do this in Mercurial? I don't want to use mercurial.ini file. If yes, how can I implement it with Merucial.Net?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you clone the repository only using the command line client? Meaning, if you didn't use Mercurial.Net, but only the command line client, `hg`, do you know if there are any parameters to it that would make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right solution.

With Mercurial.NET you can clone repositories easily like you did it in the command like client.
The URL should looks like the following:

```
http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@bitbucket.org/user/repo
```

So you can use this URL to process the clone with the Mercurial.NET library..